# How to add border like path around custom shape

Tags: css, clip-path

[image]

I need to do the image like the attached one.
I did the polygon with the image inside but I can't add the blue birder. I use clip-path for the polygon with pseudo classes.  How can I add the blue skewed border?

```css
.clip-each-blue {
  width: 100px;
  height: 90px;
  position: relative;
}

.clip-each-blue:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
}

.clip-each-blue,
.clip-each-blue:after {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 50%);
  background: #4850be;
}

.border-style-thin {
  background-color: #4850be;
}

.content-feature-image {
  display: block;
  outline: 0;
}

.content-feature-image img {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.border-style-thin:after {
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  right: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<section id="polygon">
  <div class="clip-wrap">
    <div class="clip-each-blue-border">
      <div class="clip-each-blue">
        <a href="#" class="content-feature-image"><img src="images/section/section_2_icon_1.png" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is the following:

```css
.clip-each-blue {
  width: 100px;
  height: 90px;
  position: relative;
}

.clip-each-blue:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
}

.clip-each-blue,
.clip-each-blue:after {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 50%);
  transform: rotate(90deg); /* Rotate polygon to match desired output. */
  background: #4850be;
}

.border-style-thin {
  background-color: #4850be;
}

.content-feature-image {
  display: block;
  outline: 0;
}

.content-feature-image img {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.border-style-thin:after {
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  right: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
}

/* New stuff. */

.clip-each-blue-border {
    position: absolute;
    left: 25px;
}

.clip-border {
  border: 4px solid #4850be;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateX(60deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-45deg);
}

.clip-wrap {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section id="polygon">
  <div class="clip-wrap">
    <div class="clip-each-blue-border">
      <div class="clip-each-blue">
        <a href="#" class="content-feature-image"><img src="images/section/section_2_icon_1.png" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Insert div to transform to isometric frame. -->
    <div class="clip-border"></div>
  </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Really appreciate your help. Thank you so much. It works perfectly well.

Comment: @Jenny you're welcome! Consider accepting it as an answer to let others know that it has been solved.

Comment: You just click on the check mark beside the answer. Thank you.